# Convert grid en Geotiff

Tags: gdal

Since the gdal version  3.5.1-1, this command no longer works under cygwin.

file=toto.grd
tif=toto.tif
gdal_translate $file -of GTiff $tif   -a_srs EPSG:2154

file=toto.grd
tif=toto.tif
gdal_translate $file -of GTiff $tif   -a_srs EPSG:2154

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.